# What to fill under occupation if you have quit your job

Tags: applications, schengen-visas, freelance

I have worked as a Software Engineer for around 4 years, but I do not have a permanent job right now (aside from some freelance work). My passport says my profession is Software Engineer.

I am visiting Germany for a job interview. I have the required documents from the company interviewing me.

In the visa application form, under occupation, should I choose `No Occupation`, or should I choose an occupation (Software Engineer is not listed. The closest I can find is 'Computer Expert'). If I do choose an occupation should I keep the Employer's Name blank or should I put N/A?

[This](https://videx.diplo.de/videx/) is a link to the application form for your reference.

Comment: You do have a profession (computer expert), you're just not employed at the moment. Perhaps the question should be whether that portion can be left blank, or whether selecting an occupation requires completion of the other fields.

Comment: I guess the question is whether "occupation" refers to the kind of work you typically do (= "profession"), or the kind of work you are currently employed to do (= "job"). Dictionaries I checked show both definitions.  Maybe you ought to contact the embassy and ask.

Comment: Choose "Computer Expert", that's it

Comment: You should choose "Can't Tell"

Comment: Something I always did when I wasn't actively employed was mark "Student" on customs forms since I'm always trying to learn about something. I don't know if this is good advice or if it will hurt your application though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have an occupation still - you aren't switching to being a doctor or farmer, right? You just don't have an employer. They are separate questions for a reason.

- for occupation, choose what you did at your old job and intend to do at the new one. If your title isn't there, choose whatever is closest to it.
- for employer, leave it blank if you can, or write "none" if you can't.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I edited the question with some more detail (specifically the sentence about doing some freelance work). Can you update your answer if that extra information needs a change?

Comment: doing freelancing as a software engineer only strengthens your position that your occupation is software engineer. I suppose it's possible you could put "Freelance" under employer also. I don't know the consequences of that for a visa application.

Comment: @KateGregory Freelance what though? Graphics designer, shoe shiner, lawn mower, consultant, bedtime cuddler?

Comment: if you have filled in your occupation, that answers "freelance what?" If I said my employer was IBM would you retort "IBM what though?" and the same list of possible activities? There are two questions. What do you do? Who do you do it for? They have separate answers.
"

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to make it accurate. If you don't have a job, then say that you don't have a job. Saying that you have a job while you don't might be seen as an attempt to trick the decision process and will not play in your favor, especially if it is unveiled at a point.

In the reason for the travel, you could specify that you are coming for a job interview.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. I have been doing a bit of freelancing during my unemployed time. Do you think I can say that I am a freelance 'Computer Expert'?(I will update my question with that).

Comment: Yes being a freelance is widely recognized as a true job occupation so you can certainly put it if this is your current status.

Comment: Saying that you have no profession whatsoever is not a good idea on a Visa application, especially when there is no need to do so (as is the case here). Profession != Job. -1